# Removing comma from numbers in R

Tags: r, string

My numbers have “,” for 1,000 and above and R considers it as factor. I want to switch two such variables from factor to numeric (Actually both variables are Numbers, but R considers them as factor for some reason (data is imported from excel). To change a factor variable `mydata$x1` to numeric variables I use the following code but it seems not to work properly and some values change, for example it changes 8180 to zero! and it happened many other values as well. Is there other ways to do so without such issues?

```
mydata$x1<- as.numeric(as.character(mydata$x1))
```

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your data using `dput(head(rcffull))`

Comment: You are right the original character is "8,180", probably the comma changes it into "NA" and I coded all "NA"s to 0. is there a way to fix it so that it is not "8,180" to "NA"? Maybe gsub will help.

Comment: Please rewrite the question so that it reflects the comma issue. Please follow the instructions you have been given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it seems as though the problem is that you have saved your numeric data as characters in Excel (instead of using format to display the commas) you may want a function like this.

```
#' Replace Commas Function
#'
#' This function converts a character representation of a number that contains a comma separator with a numeric value.
#' @keywords read data
#' @export
replaceCommas<-function(x){
  x<-as.numeric(gsub("\\,", "", x))
}
```

Then

```
rcffull$RetBackers <- replaceCommas(rcffull$Returning.Backers)
rcffull$NewBackers <- replaceCommas(rcffull$New.Backers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that G5W is asking for `dput` ouput is that he (we) are unable to figure out where something that displays as `8180` when it's a factor might not properly be converted with that code. It's not because of leading or trailing spaces (which would not appear in a `print`-version of a factor. Witness this test:

```
>  as.numeric(as.character(factor(" 8180")))
[1] 8180
> as.numeric(as.character(factor(" 8180 ")))
[1] 8180
```

And the fact that it gets converted to 0 is a real puzzle since generally items that do not get recognized as parseable R numerics will get coerced to NA (with a warning).

```
> as.numeric(as.character(factor(" 0 8180 ")))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

We really need the `dput` output from the item that displays as "8180" and its neighbors.

Comment: Sure I will share the dput output. I was on my way.

Comment: You are right the original character is "8,180", probably the comma changes it into "NA" and  I coded all "NA"s to 0. is there a way to fix it so that it is not "8,180" to "NA"? Maybe gsub will help.

Comment: The comma changes it to a *string*  which by default will be read as a factor.