# why value changed after I convert the variable from factor to numeric

Tags: r

after I imported a csv file to R, I noticed that the variable "MFR" was read by R as factor, but in fact it should be numeric.

```
head(FY18ADM)



      SKU1    SKU2    SKU3      MFR   FY
1 TF018AAE HA158AC HM610AC 4,485.18 FY18
2 TF018AAE HA156AC HM610AC 4,485.18 FY18
3 H7P74BAE HA158AC    <NA> 2,409.75 FY18
4 H7P74BAE HA156AC    <NA> 2,409.75 FY18
5 TF198AAE HA156AC HM610AC 9,652.60 FY18
6 TF201AAE HA156AC HM610AC 4,147.60 FY18

str(FY18ADM)

...
$ MFR      : Factor w/ 57996 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 37684 37684 21073 21073 56149 36574 50464 55246 44319 27316 ...
```

I converted this variable "MFR" from factor to numeric. Then the value changed, which is very weird. Does anyone know why the value would change?

```
FY18ADM$MFR <- as.numeric(as.factor(FY18ADM$MFR))
head(FY18ADM)

      SKU1    SKU2    SKU3   MFR   FY
1 TF018AAE HA158AC HM610AC 37684 FY18
2 TF018AAE HA156AC HM610AC 37684 FY18
3 H7P74BAE HA158AC    <NA> 21073 FY18
4 H7P74BAE HA156AC    <NA> 21073 FY18
5 TF198AAE HA156AC HM610AC 56149 FY18
6 TF201AAE HA156AC HM610AC 36574 FY18
```

To solve the problem, I had to change the data type in csv file to currency.  I believe there should be a way to do it in R. I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: R doesn't know how to coerce "4,485.18" to numeric, so it returned the underlying value (37684) associated with that particular factor level. Very common mistake.

Comment: If you use `readr::read_csv()` it should detect and format the `MFR` column as numeric. And if it doesn't you can specify `cols(MFR = col_number())`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910861/removing-comma-from-numbers-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", FY18ADM$MFR))` after you read in the csv file to R. This will replace the commas in the MFR variable.

No need to use `as.factor`.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried: FY18ADM$MFR <- gsub(",", "", FY18ADM$MFR)
FY18ADM$MFR <- as.numeric(as.factor(FY18ADM$MFR)) it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried as.numeric(gsub(",", "", FY18ADM$MFR))  now it works. Thank you so much!