# How to transform convert units of g to mm and ml to mg in R, using tidyverse and base R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to create my own function that allows me to convert units. (This is because I am working within a closed environment, with no access to downloading libraries, in R until next week.)

I want to transform g into mg, and mL into mg. In the same variable I have mg, g, mL. Therefore I am hoping the function will dissociate between the units to that it does the correct conversion when needed. Also, I am hoping to get a mix of tidyverse library with R base libraries.

This is the output I want.

```
table <- tibble::tibble(dosage_unit = c("411 mg", "0.12 g", "11.28 mL", "8 mL"), 
                        convert_mg = c("411 mg", "120 mg", "11,280 mg", "8 000 mg"))
```

As you can see the first row is in mg and it will be preserved but the rest are not in mg, thus needed to conververt.

Can someone help?

Comment: This can't be done without more information: presumably the amount of drug per unit volume.

Comment: I don't get the question... why would you convert ml into mg. You use once a , as separator, then a space as separator. Once there is mL, once there is ml... Is the question change all `l` into `g` and if there is no `m` in the original value, then devide by `.001`?

Comment: @drmariod  it was a mistake. I corrected it

Comment: There are still things that doesn't make sense... why is 11.28 mL 11,280 mg, and 8 mL 8 000 mg? Please get ur example correct first and explain what u want to do...

Comment: The `dosage_unit` is the input and `convert_mg` is the desired result, right? Am I reading your example correctly?

Comment: @Damian - yes indeed!

Comment: @Limey - thank you. May I have some literature on this? I looked into this and I am learning the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Damian's answer is correct if all you want to do is rescale grammes to milligrammes and litres to millilitres (and vice vera in both cases).  But you also ask for a conversion between millilitres and milligrammes.

The (milli-)litre is a unit of volume and the (milli-)gramme is a unit of mass.  There is no unique conversion between the two.  You also need to know density in the case of a pure substance or concentration in the case of a solution.

@Peter's solution assumes a relative density of 1 (ie water at standard temperature and pressure).  It is therefore not generic.  [Lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead), for example, has a density of 11.34 g/cm^3, or 11.34 g/mL.  So when converting between mass and volume of lead, a factor of 11.34 is required.

Similarly, with solutions - which, given your variable names, is what I think you are dealing with - you need to know the concentration of the drug in the solution.  For example, 1 mL of a solution with a drug concentration of 1 mg/mL contains 1 mg of drug but 1mL of a 10 mg/mL solution contains 10 mg of drug.

Comment: your comment about conversion coefficients and solution concentrations are well made. Note the OP does not ask for conversion from litres to millilitres; the conversion coefficient (1000) between mL and mg is implicit in the OP's question; both answers use this value. There may in fact be two parts to this question: 1) a coding solution and 2) defining the correct conversion factor; the coding solution can be correct   , but to get the correct conversion the conversion  coefficient needs to be known.

Comment: The outputs from both solutions (@Peter and mine) show the same output values, which were explicitly listed in the original post. These density and concentration adjustments might be important, but weren't described  in the original post as part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a function to do this and that there might be some concern about access to R packages.  With that in mind, you might want to write a base R function

```
convert_units <- function(x) {
    
    # extract the numeric value
    value <- as.numeric(sub("\\s.*$", "", x))
    
    # extract the measument unit
    unit <- sub("^.*\\s+", "", x)
    
    # convert values based input measurement unit
    value <- ifelse(unit == "g", value * 100, value)
    value <- ifelse(unit == "mL", value * 1000, value)
    # Output NA for unknown measuremetn unit
    value <- ifelse(unit %in% c("mg", "g", "mL"), value, NA)
    
    # return result with formatting
    paste(value, "mg")
}

convert_units(c("411 mg", "0.12 g", "11.28 mL", "8 mL"))
```

Result

```
[1] "411 mg"   "12 mg"    "11280 mg" "8000 mg"
```

Comment: what the sub and "\\s.*$" does?

Comment: when I apply the function on a variable in a table, I do not get the output

Comment: The regular expression matches a chunk of text that begins with a whitespace character all the way to the end of the text.

Comment: Does this work? `tibble::tibble(dosage_unit = c("411 mg", "0.12 g", "11.28 mL", "8 mL")) %>% mutate(convert_mg  = convert_units(dosage_unit))`

Comment: also, I get NA for numbers with 1,200 mL or 1,200 gr . Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you would need to add another `ifelse()` line to specify how to handle cases where `unit == "gr"`, and add "gr" to the list of known units: `unit %in% c("mg", "g", "mL")`

Comment: sorry, I did not mean gr, I meant comma for thousands ? like 1,200

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910861/removing-comma-from-numbers-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

With assumed conversion factors in the case of conversion from mg to mL.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# conversion coefficient mL to mg, implicit in question

ml_to_mg <- 1000

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(convert_mg = case_when(str_detect(dosage_unit, "mg") ~ dosage_unit,
                                str_detect(dosage_unit, "g") ~ paste(as.numeric(str_extract(dosage_unit, "[\\d.]+"))*100, "mg"),
                                str_detect(dosage_unit, "mL") ~ paste(format(as.numeric(str_extract(dosage_unit, "[\\d.]+"))*ml_to_mg, big.mark = ","), "mg"),
                                TRUE ~ "Check units"))

- output

df1

#>   dosage_unit convert_mg
#> 1      411 mg     411 mg
#> 2      0.12 g      12 mg
#> 3    11.28 mL  11,280 mg
#> 4        8 mL   8,000 mg
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(dosage_unit = c("411 mg", "0.12 g", "11.28 mL", "8 mL"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: also yours is good when you put it in a form of a function. I managed to get it done.

Comment: This assumes a density. If it is wrong, then there is no point.

Comment: @masher Answer with comment to make this explicit